# Performing concatenation within a matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an m x n matrix, how do I convert it to a column matrix of dimension (m x n) x 1?

[image]

Is there any library function in MATLAB? If not, how can I write one to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator to flatten a matrix into a column vector. You will want to first take the transpose because by default, flattening is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and your post is row-major.

```
M = rand(4,3);

M =

    0.8147    0.6324    0.9575
    0.9058    0.0975    0.9649
    0.1270    0.2785    0.1576
    0.9134    0.5469    0.9706


M = M.';


M =

    0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134
    0.6324    0.0975    0.2785    0.5469
    0.9575    0.9649    0.1576    0.9706


M = M(:);

M =

    0.8147
    0.6324
    0.9575
    0.9058
    0.0975
    0.9649
    0.1270
    0.2785
    0.1576
    0.9134
    0.5469
    0.9706
```

Comment: Thank you for this easy solution. I was initially trying to do it through loops and that made things more complex